# Best way to implement Javascript chaining in a library

Tags: javascript, chaining

I'm creating a JavaScript library. I've been trying to implement chaining.

**0: What I first came up with:**

```
function V(p) {
  return {
    add : function(addend) { return V(p + addend); },
    sub : function(subtra) { return V(p - subtra); },
  };
}
```

Using this method I can chain easily:

```
V(3).add(7).sub(5) // V(5)
```

Unfortunately the result is always a wrapped V() function, I am unable to extract the resulting value this way. So I thought about this problem a bit and came up with two semi-solutions.

**1: Passing flag to last method**

```
function V(p, flag) {
  if(flag)
    return p;
  else
    return {
      add : function(addend, flag) { return V(p + addend, flag); },
      sub : function(subtra, flag) { return V(p - subtra, flag); }
    };
}
```

Using this method I can end the chain by passing a flag to the last method I use:

```
V(3).add(7).sub(5, true) // 5
```

While this works just fine, it requires some code repetition and makes chaining less readable and my code less elegant.

**2: Using start() and end() methods**

```
_chain = false;
function V(p) {
  function Wrap(w) {
    return (_chain) ? V(w) : w;
  }
  return {
    add : function(addend) { return Wrap(p + addend); },
    sub : function(subtra) { return Wrap(p - subtra); },
    start : function() { _chain = true; },
    end : function() { _chain = false; return p; }
  };
}
```

Using this method you can do single operations with no more code:

```
V(3).add(7) // 10
```

But chaining requires two more methods, making things a lot less readable:

```
V(3).start().add(7).sub(5).end() // 5
```

So basically I'm just searching for the best way to implement chaining into my library. Ideally I'm looking for something where I can use any number of methods and don't need to terminate the chain in inelegant ways.

```
V(3).add(7).sub(5) // 5, perfect chaining
```

Comment: I'd suggest looking at the way jQuery has implemented chaining.

Comment: You'll find that `underscore.js` implements your second one with [.chain](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#chain)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Why not introducing a *private* variable and work on that? I guess that is even more convenient. Plus it's probably a good idea to have a pure "getter" that finally returns the computed value. This could look like this:

```js
function V(p) {
  var value = p;

  return {
    add: function(addend) {
      value += addend;
      return this;
    },
    sub: function(subtra) {
      value -= subtra;
      return this;
    },
    get: function() {
      return value;
    }
  };
}

console.log(V(3).add(7).sub(5).get()); // 5
```

You cannot return the `Object` in a *getter function* obviously. So you need some method where the chaining ends and returns a value.

Comment: Hmm, I guess that would work. Definitely the best proposal I've seen so far.

Comment: i don't think this actually works. you're setting p instead of value.  that should return 7

Comment: @nathan gonzales: my bad, fixed the typo.

Comment: Calm down, I wasn't copying your answer I had just come up with the same solution on my own.  I deleted my answer.

Answer (score 5):

In some cases it does need to have something similar to `end`, but in your simple arithmetic example, it does not.

```
function V(initial_val){
  if(!(this instanceof V)){
    return new V(initial_val);
  }

  var num = initial_val || 0;

  this.set = function(val){
    num = val;
    return this;
  }
  this.add = function(val){
    num += val;
    return this;
  }
  this.sub = function(val){
    num -= val;
    return this;
  }
  this.valueOf = function(){
    return num;
  }
  this.toString = function(){
    return ""+num;
  }
}
```

By adding `valueOf` and `toString` functions to the object, you can access its primitive value. That is, you can do something like:

```
var num = V(0).add(1).sub(2), another_num = 3 + num; // num = -1 and another_num = 2;
```

Answer (score 3):

I would amend Haochi's excellent answer as follows :

Using the prototype will be more efficient if you have many V objects and
in the toString function I invoke the generic number toString with whatever
arguments you care to give it.

```
function V (n) {
  if (!(this instanceof V)) {
    return new V (n);
  }

  this.num = +n || 0;
  return this;
}

V.prototype = {
  set: function (val) {
    this.num = val;
    return this;
  },
  add: function (val) {
    this.num += val;
    return this;
  },
  sub: function (val) {
    this.num -= val;
    return this;
  },
  valueOf: function () {
    return this.num;
  },
  toString: function () {
    return this.num.toString.apply (this.num, arguments);
  }
}
```