# Javascript: Prototype on a function which accepts an argument

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble achieving something in Javascript, and also having trouble explaining it. I'm writing an API and I want the developer to be able to write the following code:
`dashboard('name1').createPanel('name2');`

The problem is I can't figure out a way to create a function called "dashboard" (which accepts an argument 'name1') while also providing a prototype called createPanel.

Comment: Make your `dashboard` function usable as a constructor function only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have functions and object. An example:

```
 // A normal function
 function dashboard(name) {

 }
 dashboard("name1");
```

You can also prototype this function if you do a new you will have to object of class dashboard. So the example:

```
function dashboard( name ) {
    // As class
    this.name = name;
}

dashboard.Prototype.createPanel = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
    return this;  // return the reference
}

var x = new dashboard("name1"); // create object
x.createPanel( "Name2" );

// x.name will be "Name2"
```

What you want is chaining functions. All you need to do is return the object where you want to call the next function from. If you return `this` every time you can chain functions of that object like:

```
// extending the class with addProperty for chainging example

dashboard.Prototype.addProperty = function(key, value){
    this[key] = value;
    return this; // To enable chaining, return reference
} 
var x = new dashboard("name1");
x.createPanel("Niels").addProperty("A", "B").addProperty("B", "C");
```

We can chain on and on. All you need to do is return the reference where you want to continue chaining from (normally the `this` object). But can be every object you want.

Comment: Thanks this helped me a heap and gave me the terminology to Google solutions, the only problem I'm having is I want the first part of the chain to accept an argument in your example this would be x('argument').chain() or in my example dashboard('name1').createPanel('name2'); I can't seem to figure this out.

Comment: And thanks to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370538/best-way-to-implement-javascript-chaining-in-a-library I've figured it out.